# Html text doesnt react to media tag

Tags: html, css

Ey, I have some text with inputs etc next to them. And I'd like to make them responsive so that the text goes ontop of the input that was on the right of it. But I have no idea how to do this.

They do go to the left but it seems they still use the margin-left. So I thought that putting in `margin-left: 0px;` would help.

**MediaTAG and Code Snippet:**

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .block {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="CalculatorLeft" style="padding-left: 29px;" id="alles">
  <h2 style="color:#b70000;font-size:x-large;">BEREKEN DIRECT UW PRIJS</h2>
  <h2 style="color:lightgrey;font-size:medium;">Voor het schuren van uw houten vloer</h2>
  <div class="block">
    <label>Aantal vierkante meters<sup>2</sup></label>
    <input id="metersinput" type="text" placeholder="Aantal vierkante meter" style="border:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #b70000;margin-left: 90px;width:200px;" onchange="pr2()" />
  </div><br>
  <div class="block">
    <label>V-naden aanwezig</label>
    <select name="cars" class="" style="border:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #b70000;margin-left: 128px;width:200px;" id="state" onchange="weg(this)">
      <option value="behandeling" selected>Soort behandeling</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

  </div><br>
  <div class="block">
    <label>Soort behandeling</label>
    <div class="switch-field" style="margin-left: 132px;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: -22px;">
      <input type="radio" id="switch_left" name="switch_2" value="yes" onclick="show1();" checked/>
      <label for="switch_left">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" id="switch_right" name="switch_2" value="no" onclick="show2();" />
      <label for="switch_right">No</label>
    </div>
  </div><br>
  <div class="block">
    <label>Postcode & Huisnummer</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Postcode" style="border:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #b70000;margin-left: 90px;width:120px;" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Huisnr" style="border:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #b70000;margin-left: 25px;width:50px;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope someone can put me in the right direction, I'm not very good at this stuff.
If I need to put in the jsfiddle just comment that.

Comment: The `.block`s already have margins of 0. What you are looking at is the padding in their parent, `#alles`. Change that in the media query.

Comment: `input, select, .switch-field{ margin-left:0 !important; display: block;}`

Comment: try margin-left !important or margin:0 auto

Answer (score 1):

You can just change display of label to block so that it acts as a block level element and it will come top of input 
you can change this in media query

```
label:{ display:block}
```

Answer (score 0):

used `flexbox`. when the screen size is 600 and above added `flex-direction:column;`
and for 1000 and above added `flex-direction:row;`

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .block {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .block {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="CalculatorLeft" style="padding-left: 29px;" id="alles">
  <h2 style="color:#b70000;font-size:x-large;">BEREKEN DIRECT UW PRIJS</h2>
  <h2 style="color:lightgrey;font-size:medium;">Voor het schuren van uw houten vloer</h2>
  <div class="block">
    <label>Aantal vierkante meters<sup>2</sup></label>
    <input id="metersinput" type="text" placeholder="Aantal vierkante meter" style="border:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #b70000;margin-left: 90px;width:200px;" onchange="pr2()" />
  </div><br>
  <div class="block">
    <label>V-naden aanwezig</label>
    <select name="cars" class="" style="border:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #b70000;margin-left: 128px;width:200px;" id="state" onchange="weg(this)">
      <option value="behandeling" selected>Soort behandeling</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

  </div><br>
  <div class="block">
    <label>Soort behandeling</label>
    <div class="switch-field" style="margin-left: 132px;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: -22px;">
      <input type="radio" id="switch_left" name="switch_2" value="yes" onclick="show1();" checked/>
      <label for="switch_left">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" id="switch_right" name="switch_2" value="no" onclick="show2();" />
      <label for="switch_right">No</label>
    </div>
  </div><br>
  <div class="block">
    <label>Postcode & Huisnummer</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Postcode" style="border:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #b70000;margin-left: 90px;width:120px;" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Huisnr" style="border:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #b70000;margin-left: 25px;width:50px;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example below, I have removed the inline styling and used your .clock class as a container for floating label & input when the screen is bigger than 600px.

```css
.block {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 500px;
        }

        label {
            display: block;  
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }

        input {
            margin-top: 5px;
            border: 0px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #b70000;
            max-width: 200px;
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
            label {
                float: left;
            }

            input {
                float: right
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="CalculatorLeft" style="padding-left: 29px;" id="alles">
        <h2 style="color:#b70000;font-size:x-large;">BEREKEN DIRECT UW PRIJS</h2>
        <h2 style="color:lightgrey;font-size:medium;">Voor het schuren van uw houten vloer</h2>
        <div class="block">
            <label>Aantal vierkante meters<sup>2</sup></label>
            <input id="metersinput" type="text" placeholder="Aantal vierkante meter" onchange="pr2()" />
        </div>
    </div>
```